# Apache VHosts Configuration Question

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm wondering what the best way or what way I should do this.

I have a secure site https://www.example.com and https://www.example.com/contactus

https://www.example.com is in the directory /home/examplesite/www

https://www.example.com/contactus is in /home/contacts/docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is Linux, and you're not using a control panel, you could use a symbolic link here. It requires having the right permissions in both, and AllowSymlinks (I think) being setup in the apache configuration, but as far as I'm aware this is usually default for vhosts. Simply:

`cd /home/examplesite/www`
`ln -s /home/contacts/docs contactus`

Answer (score 1):

Actually the proper Apache method / approach would to be use an Alias instead of maintaining symlinks

Alias /contactus /home/contacts/docs

It all depends on how you want to do it.. (from the OS, or from Apache)

Hope this helps :D